# confirmation of answer/method: determine wether the set of polynomials in P2 is linear independent or linear dependent:

Tags: linear-algebra

determine whether the set of polynomials in P2 is linear independent or linear dependent:

S = {f1,f2,f3} = {1-x,2x-2x^2,1-x+x^2}

So I assume I'm supposed to find the homogeneous solution(right word?) with guassian elimination:

1 0 1 = 0

2 -1 1 = 0

0 -2 1 = 0

=

.....

1 0 0 = 0

0 2 0= 0

0 0 1 = 0

so k1 = 0, k2 = 0, k3 = 0

and therefore it is linear independent, because they are all 0.

if I take the determinent it yields -3, which also shows its independent right?

is this the right way to do it? are their other ways? better ways?

also, how would the gaussian method prove it was dependent? I want to say if a k value doesnt = 0 but I dont see how thats even possible. also if you get a row or column of 0s, does that make it no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you just made a slip in the second row of your matrix, or if there is some misunderstanding.  The coefficients of the polynomials should become the columns of your matrix:
$$\pmatrix{1&0&1\cr-1&2&-1\cr0&-2&1\cr}
  \sim\pmatrix{1&0&1\cr0&2&0\cr0&0&1\cr}\ .$$
As the system (with zeros on the RHS) has a unique solution, the polynomials are linearly independent.

This is probably the simplest way to do this kind of problem.  You could also take the determinant and find that it is $2$, which also shows the polynomials are independent.  But **note** that this will only work if you have a square matrix, whereas the above method will work in any case.

You can also use this method to show that polynomials are dependent.  For example, suppose you had the following matrix and row-reduced it:
$$\pmatrix{1&0&1\cr-1&2&-2\cr0&-2&1\cr}
  \sim\pmatrix{1&0&1\cr0&2&-1\cr0&0&0\cr}\ .$$
Then the system has the solution $(0,0,0)$ **and other solutions too**.  In fact, the complete solution is
$$k_1=-2\lambda\,,\ k_2=\lambda\,,\ k_3=2\lambda\,.$$
Since there is not a unique solution, the polynomials are linearly dependent.  Observe that you don't actually need to find this solution: just noting that the echelon form has a non-leading (non-pivot) column shows that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: what does λ mean? I must have not read far enough. and I guess its safe to say that this shows me everything I need to know about this type of problem, correct?

Comment: If you are looking at linear independence questions, surely you have studied how to find all solutions of a linear system?  The parameter $\lambda$ can be any number, for example, $(k_1,k_2,k_3)=(-2,1,2)$ or $(-4,2,4)$ or $(1,-\frac{1}{2},-1)$ or $(2\pi,-\pi,-2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

In linear algebra there's often lots of equally legitimate ways of doing things.  Which is the best is often about personal preference.  Both row reducing the (correct) matrix to find it has full rank, and computing a non-zero determinant are valid ways of showing these vectors are linearly independent.

Another way is to identify that the vectors in the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ for $P_2$ can be formed as linear combinations of the vectors in $\{1-x,2x-2x^2,1-x+x^2\}$:

\begin{align}
-(1-x)+(1-x+x^2) &= \color{blue}{x^2} & \text{by inspection} \\
\tfrac{1}{2}(2x-2x^2)+\color{blue}{x^2} &= \color{orange}{1} \\
-(1-x)+\color{orange}{1} &= x.
\end{align}
This is enough to show the linear combinations exist.  To find them explicitly, we make the substitutions indicated by the colors.

Hence $P_2=\mathrm{span}\{1,x,x^2\} \subseteq \mathrm{span}\{1-x,2x-2x^2,1-x+x^2\} \subseteq P_2$.